# I cannot figure out how to set PIN quality in SafeNet Token using C#. I am using eTPKCS11.dll and pkcs11interop library

Tags: c#, safenet

I want to set PIN policy on the token to only accept numerals with length 10 while initializing it.

Searching the web for solution I could not find a developer guide. While changing password I am getting error from the Token about incorrect PIN characters. After I am changing the PIN quality using SafeNet Authentication Client Tools the application works.  I am looking for a way to set the PIN policy from my C# application.